# Нужно переписать строки. В строке добавить некоторые слова и поменять местами числа

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я начинаю учить питон и решил упростить себе жизнь написав скрипт для изменения строки с начального вида до конечного вида.

**Итак. Есть файл, назовем его input.txt. Выглядит он так**

```
SpawnObject( "Land_Mil_Tent_Big2_4", "11951.000000 56.000000 9117.540039", "-50.999992 0.000000 -1.000000" );
SpawnObject( "Land_Mil_Tent_Big1_5", "11958.000000 54.000000 9110.500000", "-51.999996 0.000000 1.000000" );
```

**Мне нужно переписать его и сохранить в файл output.txt**
**Он должен выглядеть так.**

```
    <group name="Land_Mil_Tent_Big2_4" pos="11951.000000 56.000000 9117.540039" rpy="-1.000000 0.000000 -50.999992" a="0" />
    <group name="Land_Mil_Tent_Big1_5" pos="11958.000000 54.000000 9110.500000" rpy="1.000000 0.000000 -51.999996" a="0" />
```

Нужно заменить **`"SpawnObject( "`** на **`"    <group name="`** и *`" );"`* на **`"  a="0" />"`**
так же первую запятую в строке заменить на **`pos=`**, а вторую на **`rpy=`**
Так же. Поменять Первое и последние значения в **`rpy=`** местами
**Пример: вход:** `rpy="-51.999996 0.000000 1.000000"` **выход:** `rpy="1.000000 0.000000 -51.999996"`

Как я делал. Для каждого действия я создавал отдельный файл output.txt и добавлял после output последующую цифру.
в итоге я пришел к тому что написал это...
С файла input.txt я взял содержимое, убрал каждый перенос строки и присвоил это содержимое **`str`**

```
str = 'SpawnObject( "Land_Mil_Tent_Big2_4", "11951.000000 56.000000 9117.540039", "-50.999992 0.000000 -1.000000" ); SpawnObject( "Land_Mil_Tent_Big1_5", "11958.000000 54.000000 9110.500000", "-51.999996 0.000000 1.000000" );'

a = str.replace('SpawnObject( ', '<group name=')
b = a.replace(' );', ' a="0" />\n')
file = open('C:\\Users\\istra\\Desktop\\output2.txt', 'w')
file.write(b)
file.close()
b = open("C:\\Users\\istra\\Desktop\\output2.txt")
for i in b:
    res_str = i.replace(', ', ' pos=', 1)
    done = open("C:\\Users\\istra\\Desktop\\output3.txt", 'a')
    done.write(res_str)
    done.close()
c = open("C:\\Users\\istra\\Desktop\\output3.txt")
for i in c:
    nocoma = i.replace(', ', ' rpy=')
    res = open("C:\\Users\\istra\\Desktop\\output4.txt", 'a')
    res.write(nocoma)
    res.close()
```

**Итог**

```
<group name="Land_Mil_Tent_Big1_5" pos="11958.000000 54.000000 9110.500000" rpy="-51.999996 0.000000 0.000000" a="0" />
<group name="Land_Mil_Tent_Big1_5" pos="11970.900391 53.993900 9116.139648" rpy="39.000000 0.000000 -0.000000" a="0" />
<group name="Land_Mil_Tent_Big3" pos="11941.700195 55.200001 9108.019531" rpy="-53.000000 0.000000 -0.000000" a="0" />
<group name="Land_Mil_Tent_Big2_1" pos="11978.799805 56.000000 9126.809570" rpy="-49.999996 0.000000 0.000000" a="0" />
<group name="Land_Mil_Tent_Big1_2" pos="11960.500000 54.000000 9093.669922" rpy="130.999985 0.000000 -0.000000" a="0" />
<group name="Land_Mil_Tent_Big1_3" pos="11956.500000 54.001701 9088.959961" rpy="130.999954 0.000000 0.000000" a="0" />
```

**Но как поменять местами значения в rpy= не знаю. Не хватает знаний...**
**Подскажите чайнику**
Я уверен всю эту операцию можно сделать за меньшее количество ходов, но как я и сказал мне пока что не хватает знаний:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
txt_in = 'SpawnObject( "Land_Mil_Tent_Big2_4", "11951.000000 56.000000 9117.540039", "-50.999992 0.000000 -1.000000" );\n' \
         'SpawnObject( "Land_Mil_Tent_Big1_5", "11958.000000 54.000000 9110.500000", "-51.999996 0.000000 1.000000" );'
txt = txt_in.replace('SpawnObject( ', '').replace(' );', '').replace('"', '')
lst = txt.split('\n')

with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
    for i in lst:
        land, pos, rpy = i.split(', ')
        rpy_3, rpy_2, rpy_1 = rpy.split()
        txt_out = f'<group name="{land}" pos="{pos}" rpy="{rpy_1} {rpy_2} {rpy_3}" a="0" />\n'
        file.write(txt_out)
```

output.txt

```
<group name="Land_Mil_Tent_Big2_4" pos="11951.000000 56.000000 9117.540039" rpy="-1.000000 0.000000 -50.999992" a="0" />
<group name="Land_Mil_Tent_Big1_5" pos="11958.000000 54.000000 9110.500000" rpy="1.000000 0.000000 -51.999996" a="0" />
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!
Как я понял вы разбили rpy на 3 части и просто поменяли последовательность записи?

Comment: Да, так и сделал:)